# How to query random records in a MYSQL table while factoring in a priority system

Tags: mysql, sql

My table will look something like this

```
ID   | Priority
---------------
#1   | 25
#2   | 50
#3   | 125
#4   | 300
#5   | 500
```

For every 1000 queries I would like to (on average) retrieve ID #1 25 times, #2 50 times, #3 125 times, etc.

My table will have 1000s and eventually 100,000+ records, would it be possible to scale this?

This query would be getting ran very often so it'll need to run very fast in a large table as-well.

I'm definitely willing to reconsider table structure if theres a more efficient method - any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Select Random Entry, but Weight Towards Certain Entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417621/mysql-select-random-entry-but-weight-towards-certain-entries)

Comment: Just want to check - what would the relative weighting of #1000 be? How is the weighting calculated? (i.e, If I were to insert row #6, how would I know what to set it's weight to?) P.S., if that's something you're handling elsewhere, that's fine too.

Comment: The weighting will be calculated elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're going to struggle to find a query that is going to scale particularly well on very large data sets.

There are effectively two paths that you can go down:

1. Using a weighting table like you have, then multiplying this weighting by a random number for each row.
2. Having the count of the records with each ID in your table refect your weighting. e.g. #2 is twice as likely as #1, so #1 has 1 record and #2 has two records. If #3 is four times as likely as #2, then it would have eight records, etc. This method has a major, major drawback - if #4 is half as likely as #1, then the only solution is to double the number of records that every other type has, and then insert one record for #4. Very, very messy to keep track of.

With that in mind, here's a solution using approach 1:

```
SELECT ID
FROM tablename
ORDER BY (RAND() * Priority) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

(I'm not 100% sure of the syntax, as I'm a SQL Server / Oracle head, as opposed to MySQL, but I think this is right.)