# MySQL - How to select rows from a table, dependent on a chance of appearance

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I broke my head about this, but couldn't find a solution. Let's take the following example:

There is a game and a user can find stuff. But you can't find all the stuff equally. So there is a table with the items, and thereby a number (let's say between 0 and 5) that will say how much the chance is that this will be found.

So if you have 3 items from 5, 2 and 3:

- First item: 50% chance ( 5/(5+2+3) )
- Second item: 20% chance ( 2/(5+2+3) )
- Third item: 30% chance ( 3/(5+2+3) )

Is this possible with just SQL or do you really need another language like PHP too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Select Random Entry, but Weight Towards Certain Entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417621/mysql-select-random-entry-but-weight-towards-certain-entries)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT item , (itemNumber / (Select SUM(itemNumber) from itemTable) )*100
FROM itemTable
```

Comment: Yes, that calculates the percentages and I know how to do that, but I want to select a random row from the table, dependent on the percentage of chance to be selected actually.