# Using PHP to randomize 4 weighted items from an array without using the same one twice

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm creating a php file that displays 4 event sponsor ads.  For each sponsor I created an element in an array for their id, name, URL to site, URL for image, level of sponsor, value of sponsorship

I want to create a randomizer that will randomly populate 4 records from the array, but weight the values so that higher level sponsors appear more often than others.  I've already created the value for the weight as a percent.

The closest solution I've found to this problem is:

[MySQL: Select Random Entry, but Weight Towards Certain Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417621/mysql-select-random-entry-but-weight-towards-certain-entries)

Which suggests including this code, BUT the referenced link for the similar issue doesn't make sense to me.  It suggests using `ORDER BY -LOG(1.0 – RAND()) / Multiplier` but I'm using an array, not record results and I'm not completely clear on how this works...

It looks like array_rand will be helpful to at least generate the 4 different values, but still not sure how to weight them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445235/generating-random-results-by-weight-in-php

Answer (score 3):

You may use a custom function to sort the array based on the weight of sponsor. See [`usort`](http://php.net/usort).

```
usort($data, function ($value) {
    return rand(0, 100 - $value['weight']);
});
```

Example:

```
$data = array(
    array('name' => 'low', 'weight' => 5),
    array('name' => 'medium', 'weight' => 35),
    array('name' => 'high', 'weight' => 60)
);

$frequency = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    usort($data, function ($value) {
        return rand(0, 100 - $value['weight']);
    });
    $head = reset($data);
    if (!isset($frequency[$head['name']])) {
        $frequency[$head['name']] = 0;
    }
    $frequency[$head['name']]++;
}

print_r($frequency);

/*
Array
(
    [low] => 263
    [medium] => 328
    [high] => 409
)
*/
```

Comment: -1 | Really, you're suggesting running a closure (not to mention defining it) a 1000 times to do this simple task? Oh my!

Comment: Not at all @aefxx - the entire code is 3 lines. The 1000 iteration loop is to show that the function works. This is obvious from the print_r dump.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I'll take the downvote back. Here, have an upvote, instead!

Comment: I've actually found a way to randomize and uniquely add 4 spaces, and weight the results.  It goes something like this:

Answer (score 0):

This `ORDER BY` statement will not be executed by your application, it rather tells the DBMS to order the results returned by your query. You add a `LIMIT 4` to the query and you're set.

**EDIT**
Oh, I just read that you do not use a database.

**EDIT 2**
To really answer your question:

1. Iterate over your full array
2. Calculate each item's result using the above equation and store that along with the item's key/index in a temporary array
3. Sort the temporary array (highest value first), then trim it down to X items
4. You then have the keys/indexes of X items which were randomly chosen

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally worked everything out!

Here is how my final code went (I've separated and simplified the code here to piece-meal the tasks):

1. Create the array

   $Sponsors=array(
        array('Sponsor' => 'Sponsor1', 'Value' => '500'),
        array('Sponsor' => 'Sponsor2', 'Value' => '300'),
        array('Sponsor' => 'Sponsor3', 'Value' => '300'),
        array('Sponsor' => 'Sponsor4', 'Value' => '200'),)
         );
2. Set SponsorTotalCt = the number of sponsors and create a variable to hold the weighted percentage

   $SponsorTotalCt = count($Sponsors);
   $SponsorWeight = 0;
3. Get a total value for all the sponsorships

   $SponsorTotalAmt = 0;
   foreach($Sponsors as $array)
   {
     $SponsorTotalAmt += $array['Value'];
   };
4. Add the sponsor weight as a percent as another 'field value' in the $Sponsors array

   $i = 0; //initialize i
   while ($i < $SponsorTotalCt){ 
       foreach($Sponsors as $array)
       {
          $SponsorWeight = round($Sponsors[$i]['Value']/$SponsorTotalAmt * 100);
          $Sponsors[$i]['Weight'] = $SponsorWeight;
        };
       $i++; // count one up
   };

*Note: at this point the $Sponsors 'record listing' would look kind of like this

```
$Sponsors =
[0] 'Sponsor1','500', 38 (this last is the percent the sponsorship should be weighted)
[1] 'Sponsor2', '300', 23
[2] 'Sponsor3', '300', 23
[3] 'Sponsor4', '200', 15
```

Notice that the last set of values adds up to 100, or close to it (because of the rounding)*

1. Create a new array of 100 'records' where each row of the $Sponsors array is repeated the number of times that reflects the percentage.  i.e. Sponsor1 values will be repeated in the array 38 times

   $newSponsors = array();
   $i = 0; //initialize i
   while ($i < $SponsorTotalCt){ 
   foreach($Sponsors as $array)
   {
           $a = array_fill(0, $Sponsors[$i]['Weight'], $Sponsors[$i]);

   };
   $newSponsors= array_merge($newSponsors,$a);
   $i++; // count one up
   };
2. Finally, randomly select 3 keys from the 4 Sponsors, weighted by the value of their Sponsorships

   $spot = array_rand($newSponsors,3);

Now I only have to create the code and call the value.  YAY!

Comment: uh oh, I still have a little work to do- the array of "100" certainly weights the results by making a value appear more times, and the 'array_rand' certainly does not select the same number twice; however, there is still nothing to stop the same sponsor from appearing twice if the random selection is a duplicate of a previous selection.  Does it ever end?

Comment: what finally worked for randomizing: 'do {
 if ($A0['Sponsor'] == $A1['Sponsor'] | $A0['Sponsor'] == $A2['Sponsor'] | $A0['Sponsor'] == $A3['Sponsor']| $A1['Sponsor'] == $A2['Sponsor'] | $A1['Sponsor'] == $A3['Sponsor'] | $A2['Sponsor'] == $A3['Sponsor']) { 
  $pass = 'false';
  $spot = array_rand($newSponsors,4);
  $A0 = ($newSponsors[$spot[0]]);
  $A1 = ($newSponsors[$spot[1]]);
  $A2 = ($newSponsors[$spot[2]]);
  $A3 = ($newSponsors[$spot[3]]);
  } else {
     $pass = 'true';
 };
} while ($pass <> 'true');
'