# PHP Select random but variabeles have different weights

Tags: php, sql, random

I'm working on a simple advertisement script, I have a database with all the ads and a weight.

The ad is a picture and the weight is a number from 1 to 20 depending on it's importance (1 shows up rarely and 20 shows up a lot.

But if I'm getting this information from my database how do I sort and choose an ad to display? So can I put a weight on a variabele in a creative way? It's possible to make and array for each weight point and then select a random ad from that array but is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dagon is correct. Use the example from that other question. Again Dagon found it here: [MySQL: Select Random Entry, but Weight Towards Certain Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417621/mysql-select-random-entry-but-weight-towards-certain-entries) The comments are really helpful. You basically multiple that row by its weight. To add to that question and answers I would add the rows into an array and then randomly pick one (one array value) to display. When something has more weight just place it in that array times its weight.