# MySQL RAND(), how to factor in weight from column value

Tags: mysql

--RESOLVED--

Say you have a table for entries, where entry1 has a weight of 20, and entry2 with a weight of 80. Running a query like

```
SELECT * FROM `entries` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

will return either of the row at random. However, I wanted to factor in weight, such that entry2 has 80% chances of being drawn and entry1 has 20%.

Is there a proper/hacky way of writing this query? Previously, I had to insert 20 entries for entry1 and 80 entries for entry2 just to have each weight well represented.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL: Select Random Entry, but Weight Towards Certain Entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417621/mysql-select-random-entry-but-weight-towards-certain-entries) (**found by Googling "*mysql random weighted*"**)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. My test result looks promising. However, even with the explanation on that page, I don't understand how it worked (particularly the part where you divide by weight, what was the value of weight when the query executed?)

Comment: (*I'm not ignoring you, but I don't know enough about logarithmic math to answer you - I just found the duplicate*). That said, [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417621/mysql-select-random-entry-but-weight-towards-certain-entries#comment23635801_12301949) seems to explain it.

Comment: Thanks h2ooooooo! Appreciate it. Marked the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do what you want:

```
select *
from entries e
order by weight * rand()
limit 1;
```