# Mysql Select random rows to n times

Tags: php, mysql, random

I want to get 3 random records from my table to 90 times.

Scenario

```
  user_id     number_of_bids 
    12              20
     8               40
     6               30
```

what i want is...Get above 3 rows in random order to a specific number In fact it is `sum(number_of_bids)`...

And every row should not repeated greater than its number of bids..

I have created a query where I am getting sum of `number_of_bids`.Now second query required where these 3 records should be in random order to `sum(number_of_bids)` times and every record should not greater repeated greater than its `number_of_bids`.

Not sure it can be achieved in one query or not.But you people are experts I am sure you can help me.It will save my execution time..
    Thanks..

Comment: Do you really need that many rows? If you just wanted to get the user_id in a random weighted order so they are more likely to appear at the top based on number_of_bids then you can check out weighting results like this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417621/mysql-select-random-entry-but-weight-towards-certain-entries

Comment: Yes Because I am trying to write a cron job which will place bids in random order.So I don't want any user miss his bid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just build an array out of the rows and shuffle it:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT user_id, number_of_bids FROM table_name', PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
$results = array(); $startIndex = 0;
foreach ($stmt as $userId => $numberOfBids) {
    $results += array_fill($startIndex, $numberOfBids, $userId);
    $startIndex += $numberOfBids;
}
shuffle($results);
```

Then, you can iterate `$results` however you'd like.

Comment: this array will contain 90 records?Also the $results should not $results=array();

Comment: @AsifAsghar You mean based on the given table in your question? Yes, it should.

Comment: @AsifAsghar "Also the $results should not $results=array();" .. what do you mean by that?

Comment: Thank you..I have figure it out with the help of your code.But this not possible via query only?

Comment: As far as I'm aware MySQL isn't well suited to do such a thing.