# Select Random in SQL with multiple instances of the same value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Consider the following:

```
user_id weight
      1   2
      2   5
```

Is there a query that could select a user ID at random while using the weights to affect the odds of which ID gets chosen?

In other words, in such a scenario, is there a query that would look at this table and then choose 1 user ID at random from the following group:

```
[UserID_001, UserID_001, UserID_002, UserID_002, UserID_002, UserID_002,  UserID_002]
```

So that UserID_002 has a 5/7 chance of being selected, and UserId_001 has a 2/7 chance of being selected.

This would be like each user having a number of tickets in a raffle, User_001 has 2 tickets, and User_002 has 5 tickets. Is it possible to do such a thing with an SQL query? Or do I need to use some other method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it would be a lot easier to do this in the application level - otherwise, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417621/mysql-select-random-entry-but-weight-towards-certain-entries)

Comment: Hi @pala_ thanks for your comment, I read the link you gave and I'm now testing the following query on my database: ``SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY (RAND( ) * weight) LIMIT 1;``  this appears to be giving a random ID each time, I was wondering if I could ask, does it look correct to you?

Comment: @pala_ actually, after doing some testing, it appears this query works: ``SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY -LOG(RAND()) / weight LIMIT 1;``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a weighted sampling.  This is actually pretty easy, once you have a cumulative sum of the all the weights.

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@w := @w + weight) as cumew
      from table t cross join
           (select @w := 0) init
     ) t
where @w * rand() <= cumew
order by weight
limit 1;
```

Note in the outer query that `@w` is the sum of all the weights.  So, it multiplies this by a random number and finds the first cumulative weight that is greater than or equal to this value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for your lottery :-)

If you need see how it works, just comment last line of query `WHERE ...`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54a44/17

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, 
IF(@total IS NULL,@first:=1, @first:=@total+1) from_number,
IF(@total IS NULL,@total:=tickets, @total:=@total+tickets) to_number,
IF(@winner IS NULL,@winner:= FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) * t_sum.t_all), @winner) win 
FROM tickets
LEFT JOIN (SELECT SUM(tickets) t_all FROM tickets) t_sum
ON 1) t
WHERE win >= from_number AND win <= to_number
```